# Is there an interpreter for Python similar to Pry for Ruby?

Tags: python, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop

Is there an interpreter for Python similar to [Pry](http://pryrepl.org) for Ruby?

It is very convenient. I can stop the program wherever I want with a statement like `binding.pry`, and I can inspect the value of variables, manipulating them, etc. It's very good for finding errors.

Comment: Use `ipdb` which has `ipython` integration. Also it has a `post-mortem` option, which allows you to drop into the debugger (`ipython` shell) when an exception or error occurs.